# how to add json parse data in core data in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

This my data parsing code parsing is done.how to add that data in core data

-(void)DataRetireve
{
     deatilinfoarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://sms.instatalkcommunications.com/apireq/GetSMSCategories?t=1&h=admin&param=1"];
     ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
     [request setDelegate:self];
     [request startAsynchronous];
     }

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
  {

  NSError *error = [request error];
  NSString *responseString = nil;

  if (!error)
  {
      responseString = [request responseString];

  ```
  SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init] ;

  NSMutableArray *jsondata = [parser objectWithString:responseString];
  NSMutableArray *jsondata1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

  for(int i=0;i<jsondata.count;i++)
  {

      info *myinfo=[[info alloc]init];
      myinfo.Id=@"Id";
      myinfo.Name=@"Name";
      myinfo.IsActive=@"IsActive";

      [jsondata1 addObject:myinfo];
       NSLog(@"%@",responseString);

  }

     for(int i=0;i<jsondata1.count;i++)
     {
     info *myinfo= [jsondata1 objectAtIndex:i];

     [jsondata1 addObject:myinfo];

      }
  ```

Comment: You usually use a `UICollectionView` in these cases.

Comment: I'd definitely to got **Paint Code** for something like this. paintcodeapp.com if you're not an addict already.  i's the only way to fly - do it once and never do it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way you can use it is-

```
int yPossion = 50, xPossion = 10; int temp = 0;
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
for (int i = 0; i<50; i++){
    UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [aButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [aButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-menu.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [aButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %d",i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [aButton setFrame:CGRectMake(xPossion, yPossion, 100, 50)];

    [scrollView addSubview:aButton];
    xPossion += aButton.frame.size.width+15;
    temp++;
    if (temp==3) {
        yPossion = aButton.frame.origin.y+aButton.frame.size.height+15;
        temp = 0;
        xPossion = 10;
        [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, yPossion+50)];
    }
}
```

But if you want to it using autoLayout constrains then you can follow this [link](https://medium.com/@jsleeuw/mastering-programmatic-auto-layout-b02ed2499d79) may be it will help you.

Comment: how to set label for each button like angry ams, love ams  and all

Comment: @chetangharat The best way to design this kind of view is using UICollectionView. You can find the Ray Wender Lich Tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12 for using this.

Comment: @chetangharat Using UICollectionView you will have a lot of flexibility in design, searching and all. It will help you create a desired grid.

Comment: i use int count=20;

for(int i = 0; i < [items count]; i++){
    UILabel *label =  [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0,count,0,0)];
    label.text = @"text"; //etc...
    [label sizeToFit]; // resize the width and height to fit the text
    count+=20;
    [scrollView addSubview:label];
} but i want diff label text how can?

Comment: i know that but i have to create all the control dynamical(programmatically) so can't use drag and drop control.thats y i ask you .

Comment: @chetangharat No bro, you can customise it as you want at run time same like tableView. Just have a look about its delegate and may be you found them useful. But for your approach you have to store your title label text in a dictionary or array during when the buttons are made at same index.

Comment: yes but i can't understand dictionary concept will you give some example .?

Comment: Basically I think you should save your titles in an array or property list in same order as you want. But actually I am not sure about it, so sorry, because for this kind of help I need to know more about your approach and code and all only then I can help you.

Comment: how to set label dynamically to each button in iOS

Comment: @chetangharat The simplest way to achieve this will be, create a label every time when you are creating the button and add it as subview to your button.

Comment: Add this UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 80, 30)];
        [label setText:@"hello"];
        [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [aButton addSubview:label]; below the line [scrollView addSubview:aButton]; in above code. but again my friend I will say this is not a good approach its just a substitute.

Comment: @iDeveloper i want one help  i parse data using ASIHTTPREQUEST library i.e  ID ,NAME,MSG  i want These Parse Data Stored in core data.How to store Json Response in core data????

Comment: What help? but have you checked the code I have given above?

Comment: yes its working  now i have to parse data and save that data in the core data http://sms.instatalkcommunications.com/apireq/GetSMSCategories?t=1&h=admin&param=1  this link i use to parse data using ASIHTTPREQUEST  data parsing is done now stored that data in core data

Comment: @chetangharat Brother for this you should follow various core data tutorials available on tutsplus and raywenderlich websites. Then simply store and retrieve data using core data.